# having trouble with TabLayout using fragments and JSON

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I been trying for a while to figure this out and checked a lot of post. I am having this problem when I switch to a new tab only the XML layout is showing. Though when I start on the first tab and fragment the json content shows up how I like. I am not sure how to get the json content to change for a new tab.

Fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TVFragment extends Fragment {


    public TVFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tv_activity, container, false);


        ArrayList<String> media = new ArrayList<String>();
        media.add("movie1");
        media.add("movie2");
        media.add("movie3");


        this.loadMovieInfo(media);
//        loadMoviePoster(media);


        return rootView;
}


    private void loadMovieInfo(ArrayList<String> media) {

        Random random = new Random();


        int x = (int) random.nextInt(media.size()) * 1;

        //Use Ion to get json info for movie from movie/tv api.

        Ion.with(this)
                .load("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + media.get(x)
                        + "&apikey0000")
                .asString()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                        try {
                            // create json object
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                            //get json title and poster from the json object.
                            String name = json.getString("Title");
                            String urlString = json.getString("Poster");

                            //get TextView to display title
                            TextView mediaName = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.synopsis_text_view);
                            mediaName.setText(name);

                            /* create new DownloadImageTask class for displaying image from url. Picasso API can be used instead if wanted to view picture as well.
                                this needs to be used since the app will crash due to nature of threading, so AsyncTask is implemented.
                            */
                            new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.poster)).execute(urlString);

                        } catch (JSONException jsone) {
                            Log.wtf("Json Import problems", jsone);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Created by Samuel on 2/12/2018.
 */

public class TechnologyResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the tv_activitylayout file
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_viewpager_activity);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        MediaTypeAdapter adapter = new MediaTypeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

}
```

Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Samuel on 2/14/2018.
 */

public class MediaTypeAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public MediaTypeAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context applicationContext){
        super(fragmentManager);
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new TVFragment();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return new MovieFragment();
        }
        else {
            return new MovieFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        if(position == 0){
            return  "TV";
        } else {
            return "MOVIES";
        }

    }
}
```

tablayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

movie_activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/poster"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            />


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/synopsis_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="81dp"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/synopsis_text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="Academy Award nominee, heart-warming, hit comedy from producer Judd Apatow (Bridesmaids and Trainwreck). The Big Sick is based on the real-life courtship between Pakistan-born comedian Kumail Nanjiani (Nanjiani) and grad student Emily Gordon (Zoe Kazan) who fall in love but struggle while dealing with Emily's mysterious illness and their families culture clash. Also staring Ray Romano and Holly Hunter. Included with Prime."/>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show us your result of current and desired result.. i'm not quite understand of your question

Comment: I would like the json information to create and populate the on the new tab/xml layout file when it is selected to that position, but it is only calling it on the the 1st tab fragment that shows up on the main activity, when it's is originally called. It isn't pulling the information when the tab is changed no information is being set to the xml layout, it is just blank.

Comment: post your `xml` code and `MovieFragment` code

Comment: added info moviefragment is the same since I am just making a sample test right now.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a new class moviefragment and have to write code to fetch movies in that.

```
public class MovieFragment extends Fragment{
TechnologyResultsActivity technology;
Context context;
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context=context;
        technology= (TechnologyResultsActivity) context;
    }
    public static Fragment newInstance(Bundle bundle){
        MovieFragment movie=new MovieFragment();
        if(bundle!=null){
            movie.setArguments(bundle);
        }
        return movie;
    }

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
// this will only called when fragment is visible to user
        if(isVisible()) {
            if (Constant.isInternetConnected(homeActivity)) {
                ArrayList<String> media = new ArrayList<String>();
        media.add("movie1");
        media.add("movie2");
        media.add("movie3");
loadMovieInfo(media)

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(homeActivity, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    }

private void loadMovieInfo(ArrayList<String> media) {

        Random random = new Random();


        int x = (int) random.nextInt(media.size()) * 1;

        //Use Ion to get json info for movie from movie/tv api.

        Ion.with(this)
                .load("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + media.get(x)
                        + "&apikey0000")
                .asString()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                        try {
                            // create json object
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                            //get json title and poster from the json object.
                            String name = json.getString("Title");
                            String urlString = json.getString("Poster");

                            //get TextView to display title
                            TextView mediaName = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.synopsis_text_view);
                            mediaName.setText(name);

                            /* create new DownloadImageTask class for displaying image from url. Picasso API can be used instead if wanted to view picture as well.
                                this needs to be used since the app will crash due to nature of threading, so AsyncTask is implemented.
                            */
                            new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.poster)).execute(urlString);

                        } catch (JSONException jsone) {
                            Log.wtf("Json Import problems", jsone);
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it out.